# How does 3-sat work in laymen's terms?

Tags: computer-science, computability, np-complete

I know only basic math like so: (+,-,x,\,). And I studied a little bit of programming up to the point of knowing a little bit about Boolean values.I desperately want to understand the 3-sat question fully so I can solve it, but no one ever gives examples I can understand. Please give me a few example problems with full explanations on what they want, then give one example question that If solved will also solve 3-sat. I know they want someone to assign values to variables in a certain way to where the expression is always true,but I can't wrap my head around what that actually means? Other people have asked the same question as me and got a complicated explanation. Please explain to me as simple as possible how does 3-sat work? I know there was an example once that went something like this: A or B , C and D but not A. so the answer is obviously B ,C and D. They are asking about puting values in variables in a way were the expression always evaluates true, but I can't comprehend that concept to even try and solve. Please help. I've seen this example before  x1∧x2∨x3 and I did a little research and I keep getting this symbol ^ with an explanation that says A and B are true if A and B are true. I get the logic of that statement but U don't get how those symbols make since in an example. Please clarify so that I can finally be able to try and solve it.I don't know much about c++ so please be sure to give an example problem fully explaining how it works. Thanks please don't tell that I shouldn't study this problem just because I don't know a lot of math. I'm sure I don't need to be a math or computer expert to figure out the basics and understanding of this problem so I can TRY and solve it.

Comment: It is a grave misconception that "every problem should be easily understood". Moreover if you want to actually attempt to solve it, and not just understand the formulation of the problem itself. If you are serious about solving the problem then you should pick up several books and learn the basics of propositional calculus and understand the problem in full so you can attack it. Saying "I don't get it, but I want to solve it" comes off as nothing but childish.

Comment: Thats bull. Anyone can learn and comprehend anything. Even a 5 year old could be taught the most difficult mathematical and scientific things, but if someone were to learn it quick , it would take everyday metaphors.

Comment: My cousin is a computer tech and it took him years to learn everything he knows. I told him to take a day and come up with a bunch of easy metopgors that all go together fluently in a story. The next day it took me 2 hours to learn and another hour to review it and keep it in my head. So if I could learn that in 3 hours then practically anyone could learn anything. It just takes someone who cares about you to take the time and explain it. The guy on here is tired of trying to explain it to me, yet he was using the kind of easy metaphors that anyone could understand.

Comment: I was very close to fully getting it until he got tired.

Comment: I used to think that. But understanding and wanting to solve a problem that many capable people thought about is far from the same thing.

Comment: Well it is true that understanding and solving a problem are different things, because if I understand everything about the problem doesent mean I understand everthing about that field, but it all it takes for some one to solve something is the right amount of knowlede, which is'ent much of you look in the right places

Comment: Let me tell you a story, I once wanted to get into chess as a pro, but I dident know alot about how the game worked. So I tried to beating the chess Titan program on windows. I lost horribly, so I started watching videos on how masters play and how trps work. I took on the computer again and lost. I looked on youtube to see if any one beat it, but no one did, and the ones who said they did lied because the program was moving to fast and making weaker moves. Which meant it wasent on level 10 like they said.

Comment: So I got my cousin who is very entelligent, to try and beat it, but he dident know how to play. I taught him by playing me in a few matches and even though he lost because he fell for most of my traps. That same day we both took on lv 10 at once. Hi strategy was brilliant yet he was lazy when it came to seeing traps. So I spotted all of them out the entire game. 3 hours later we won.

Comment: To this day he claims it as his victory but we did it, and I was'nt even good at chess, Injust knew where to look for traps. And beating lv10 is equivelant to beating a grandmaster. So do you see why I think it isent neccesary to know much to solve hard things?

Comment: Excuse my spelling but the spelling corrector doesent offer to fix every word all the time.

Comment: It's cute and naive that you think academic math and computer science are comparable with chess against the computer...

Comment: Your just close minded because you had to learn everything the hard way, and having someone learn something that took you years, only taking me a week is inconceivable to you, since you'd feel so cheated.

Comment: Oh wow, you know me so well... Go ahead and prove me wrong mister "I can't even understand the problem".

Comment: Hey, I'm not saying your completely wrong, I'm just saying what I believe to be true. I know that there are easier ways to learn things than people would like others to believe. If I hired a math teacher and I paid him by the hour, there's no way he's going to try and teach me as much as he can at once. He would want to get paid more by taking more time. And even if he taught me for free and taught me everything at once, and I was getting it, he would feel like he was cheated, having to Learn the short cuts by taking the long roads.

Comment: If he just told me the short cuts then why did he take years to learn it. I'm not saying this is as easy as it sounds ,but it seems logical enough to make sense. I haven't found one thing I could possibly think of that couldn't be learned easily with a proper teacher.

Comment: In fact , if you don't understand the problem , then why did you comment on it from the beginning. Clearly you have to much free time . DUNK!!! right in the basket . Jk

Comment: You know what, go ahead and prove me wrong. Do your very best and be the world leading expert on $3$-SAT. In twenty years, give me a call and let me know that I was right, it was in fact very hard work to *understand* the problem properly.

Comment: That sounds great,  in fact I've already solved the PvsNP example question. So all I have to do is format it to mathematical terms and the million is mine :)

Answer (score 6):

**THE SHORT VERSION**

3-SAT is basically a bunch of questions separated into groups of threes.  If at least one in each group is true, we say it is *satisfiable*.  If not, we say it's *unsatisfiable*.

---

**THE LONG VERSION**

**AN EXAMPLE**

For example, we can think of things in the kitchen.  We can look at 4 things; an oven, a microwave, a toaster, and a refrigerator.  Now we take groups of three of them.  For example, we can take the oven, the microwave, and the toaster as one group.  We can take the oven, the toaster, and the refrigerator as another group.

Now, we can ask if one in each group is on?  Returning to our example, we ask

(is the oven on?) OR (is the microwave on?) OR (is the toaster on?)

...and for the other group

(is the oven on?) OR (is the toaster on?) OR (is the refrigerator on?)

That's how we get groups of 3 for 3-SAT.  We combine them together to ask:

((is the oven on?) OR (is the microwave on?) OR (is the toaster on?))

AND

((is the oven on?) OR (is the toaster on?) OR (is the refrigerator on?))

That's the essence of 3-SAT.  We use variables to represent the questions.  So, for example, we could say that

$O$ means Is the oven on?

$M$ means Is the microwave on?

$T$ means Is the toaster on?

$R$ means Is the refrigerator on?

Then our example can be phrased like an equation:

((is the oven on?) OR (is the microwave on?) OR (is the toaster on?)) becomes
($O$ OR $M$ OR $T$)

((is the oven on?) OR (is the toaster on?) OR (is the refrigerator on?)) becomes
($O$ OR $T$ OR $R$)

**COMBINING THINGS**

So putting everything together, we have:

($O$ OR $M$ OR $T$) AND ($O$ OR $T$ OR $R$)

That's how we get the equation form of 3-SAT.

**THE COMPLETE PROBLEM**

There's one more thing we can do.  We can ask the opposite.  So instead of asking, "is the oven on?", we can ask "is the oven off?".  We call "Is the oven on?" $O$, and we call "Is the oven off?" NOT $O$.  So now we can say NOT $O$, NOT $M$, NOT $T$, NOT $R$ if we want.

Here's a sample equation of this:

($O$ OR $M$ OR (NOT $T$)) AND ($O$ OR (NOT $T$) OR $R$)

This is:

((is the oven on?) OR (is the microwave on?) OR (is the toaster OFF?)) becomes

($O$ OR $M$ OR (NOT $T$))

AND

((is the oven on?) OR (is the toaster OFF?) OR (is the refrigerator on?)) becomes

($O$ OR (NOT $T$) OR $R$)

That's the gist of it.  It's really just making sure that at least one thing in each group of three is true.  In other words, one thing in each group has a yes answer.  If this is true, then we say the whole thing is true, or SATISFIABLE.  If not, then we say the whole thing is false, or UNSATISFIABLE.

Comment: Nice job, Matt. +1

Comment: Thank you very much Matt, I just received your answer and I haven't read it yet but it's exactly what I wanted. I'm about to read it when I get home, I'm so exited to finally get a good answer :D  THANKS FOR EVERYTHING !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user92684: You're welcome.  Let me know if there's anything else you'd like to know about 3-SAT.

Comment: Yeah, there are a few more things I'd like to know, thanks. I understand everything you put but I'm not seeing the EXACT conflict with the question.o.k let's say that out of your example I decided to give O-oven a value, let's say I is on, then that means O is also on in the second clause. So by default all the other objects could be given the value off making the Oven the only thing on , there for making both clauses true. Now I did a little research and found that some clauses could cancel each other out and I'm thinking that could be the problem, yet I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: I'm sorry I screws up on the above comment, I meant to say O is on. I know what A v B means yet in not sure how -a works. I guessing the problem with 3-sat is the v symbols. Please give me examples on situations on how values need to go into variables and what kind of situations could be solutions, and which could be problems , thank you

Comment: Please give me examples where you show all the problems with variables and there values, and how values need to be put in variables so they can make an expression true. I still can't see a problem with making clauses easily true. Please create scenarios that are easy to solve, and the ones that show conflict and are harder to solve, basically I just want to know the whole problem. I know some statements can be canceled out by others, and in wondering if that's the problem. That's all for now, thank you, well talk later

Comment: @lordaizen21:  We could have $(M \lor T \lor O) \land (M \lor T \lor \neg O)$, where $\neg O$ means not $O$.  In this case the $O$ values cancel each other out, and we would need either the microwave or the toaster to be on.

Comment: O.k but are their actual scenarios that are like the above equation that present a problem to PvsNP. Is the problem with the above scenario and 3-sat figuring out how many times you must try different ways to turn something on and off until the correct things on both sides is off and the right things on?Basically saying trying all possible combinations leads to a long problem. Lets say the -O in (M ∨ T ∨ -O) is the problem figuring this out. Then right from the beginning I could see that you could quickly eliminate O as something that can turn on.

Comment: Then you could randomly turn anything else on and the conflict is gone with trying different combinations. So I still can't find a scenario where it gets longer in polynomial time to answer. I don't even know if hard problems are even the conflict of PvsNP. Could you please clarify this a little for me?

Comment: @lordaizen21: In the 3-SAT problem, we are given a formula.  It doesn't change.  The problem is to figure out if it's satisfiable or not.  It doesn't mean we try to figure out the number of ways to turn things on and off.  It really just means we are trying to find if we have a yes answer to one of the questions in each group of three.  None of the questions or variables change.

Comment: @Matt Groff 4: Just to clarify something I put above. If you eliminate the O because of the -o then you could turn something else on randomly like T for instance, then turn everything else off. So as I was saying above I fail to see a complete problem. If me asking you to many questions is a problem, then accept my apologys. I've just really been trying to understand this question for a long time. If this is to much of an inconvenience then it's o.k if you don't want to bother with this anymore. Thank you for all your help so far

Comment: @lordaizen21:  There's really not a problem with answering the questions until you have at least 8 groups of questions.  I'll use + to denote OR, * to denote AND, and - to denote NOT.  Then consider (O + M + T) * (O + M + -T) * (O + -M + T) * (O + -M + -T) * (-O + M + T) * (-O + M + -T) * (-O + -M + T) * (-O + -M + -T).  This is the simplest formula that can't be satisfied.  But as you can see, the formula is big.  So the problem is easy until you have LOTS of groups of questions.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @Matt Groff 4: yes. Your recent details helped a lot, but do you determine what is on and what is off before answering the problem? Or is that something I have to figure out. If O is determined before hand to be on but everything else to be off, then you get (O + -M + -T) .

Comment: @lordaizen21:  The formulas are determined beforehand.  Then the trick is to see if there's a way to answer one question in each group.  For instance, in the example I just gave, we could guess that the oven might be on; in other words, we have $O$.  This works for 4 of the groups: (O + M + T), (O + M + -T), (O + -M + T), and (O + -M + -T).  However, that still leaves 4 questions: (-O + M + T), (-O + M + -T), (-O + -M + T), (-O + -M + -T).  We could guess that M is true; that would answer (-O + M + T) and (-O + M + -T).  That leaves (-O + -M + T) and (-O + -M + -T).

Comment: But if you don't know what's on and off then I'm guessing you have to try out all possible scenarios until you find what's on and off. But If this is the case then what does putting values into variables mean and how does it work? Does it mean give one of the letters a value of on or off?

Comment: @Matt Groff 4: Hmmm, very enteresting, I'm going to go home and think this over, I should have everything I need now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @lordaizen21:  You're basically right; we have to try a lot of possible scenarios before we find something that works.  Sometimes nothing works, and then we say that the problem is unsatisfiable.  You're right about putting values into variables.  They're either on or off, and to get technical, scientists say true or false.

Comment: @lordaizen21: You're welcome.

Comment: @Matt Groff 4: im sorry to bother you again but you put : The formulas are determined before hand. But is it determined that O is on before hand?

Comment: And if so is it also determined what else is on and off before hand as well?

Comment: Or is it unknown what is on and off at all until you start guessing and experimenting with scenarios, getting true and false feeling out what's on and off?

Comment: @lordaizen21: It's unknown what is what.  The only thing that is known is the formula.  So we can make guesses to see if any fit the formula.

Comment: @Matt Groff 4: I'm a little confused on a few things.In your example, the whole equation could not be satisfied. But if I find a way to easily tell if a problem could be satisfied or not, then doesn't that solve 3-sat?

Comment: @Matt Groff 4: And also, if I had a question that asked what if anything is on, and I was using the equation (O + M + -T)*(O + -M  + T)*(-O + M + T)*(O + M + T), then wouldn't that mean O is on simply because it was asked about being off the least amount of times? Since I can do this with any problem I get, it then becomes an instant answer to any equation.

Comment: I read on another post somewhere  on this site that if -a is true then a is false. Doesn't that just mean (-a + b)? Also please give me a challenging long equation that tries to disprove my method, because I don't know if my method works for every problem in 3-sat. I also don't know if that is even the solution that is needed. I f you want, give me an equation with (A v B)*(C ^ D) type stuff. I think ^ means if A or B is true, then A and B are true. And I think v means the opposite.

Comment: I think if I had a problem to work on with these symbols then maybe it defeats my solution of finding the one that is questioned of  being false the least.

Comment: Please explain to me how this shoulder be the solution to 3-sat.

Comment: @lordaizen21: 3-SAT only includes AND ($\land$), OR ($\lor$), and NOT ($\neg$).  The operation EXCLUSIVE OR ($^$) is not allowed to be used in 3-SAT.  In regular SAT, all kinds of operations are allowed.  But 3-SAT only allows the three operations AND, OR, and NOT.  So in a way it's simpler than SAT, which I believe is why a lot of people work with it.  As for A and -A, -A just means the opposite of A.

Comment: @Matt Groff: I'm so close to understanding this and wanting to try and solve this, yet I still don't understand every single thing. I'm sure it's very easy for you to understand this kind of work because you are a very intelligent man, but even though I have a basic understanding of math, U think I can still do this. So If it hasn't been to much of a bother, there is just a few small concepts I'm not getting.

Comment: @Matt Groff: I don't excactly understand this : Is there a way to assign values to variables to make all the clauses true, END QUOTE . I read on another persons example that described a variable as (A, B , C) but he contradicted himself saying v , ^ , - are variables. So I'm a bit confused to what's what. Lets say for now v ^ are variables. In an equation, are you suppose to change the variables to find if something fits? or do you just keep them the same and try and figure out how to give a right answer to each question.

Comment: @Matt Groff:I don't understand how these situational thins work. If you have the time, please give me a satisfiable equation that shows how someone would try to figure it out. and the steps and limits on what they can do to try and solve it. BTW, one more thing, in your earlier example the equation was unsatisfiable, but does it matter or not if it was or wasn't ? I think it doesn't matter, as long as you can quickly answer each question and call it satisfiable , or quickly prove why an answer is unsatisfiable. And prove you could do that with all equations ,am I right?

Comment: @Matt Groff: please answer as many questions from here as you can, because if I don't get these answers, then I'm never going to fully understand 3-sat, and I'll keep trying to find out the same answers forever. Thanks

Comment: I'm giving up on 3-sat, it will take to many years to figure out. btw, did you ever understand my solution to 3-sat?

Comment: @lordaizen21:  You don't have to give up.  Could you explain your solution again?

Comment: @lordaizen21:  It looks like the end result that you get is the same as addition and subtraction of values for O, M, and T.  In the end, this usually doesn't work, so it probably won't solve 3-SAT.  I'm guessing that you may want to try learning about _truth tables_.  They kind of SHOW us what works and what doesn't.  Here's a link if you're interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table .  I think that studying up on these may help a lot.

Comment: Thanks , it looks like even you don't understand 3-sat as well as I thought. I deleted my solution just in case it is the right answer and someone else tries to see it. Thank you for all your help, when I find the time I'm going to start studying it. I have one other question on something else, but I was blocked from asking anymore questions. I guess I'll just have to forget about it. Anyway thanks for everything :)